# Change shell used to run "shell commands" in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

In GHCi, a shell command can be executed using `:!<command>`. By default, it seems that the `sh` shell is used:

```
Prelude> :!echo $0
/bin/sh
```

I have a number of aliases and custom functions defined for the shell I use generally on my system (`fish`), and I'd like to use these from GHCi but not have to translate them into `sh`-compatible versions.

Is there a way of changing the shell GHCi uses to execute `:!` commands? I haven't been able to find any `:set` options for this, nor any command-line arguments to GHCi to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`:!` command in current versions of ghci](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/22733532171330136d87533d523f565f2a4f102f/ghc/GHCi/UI.hs#L1205) is a call to [`System.Process.system`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.1.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:system)

```
-- | Entry point for execution a ':<command>' input from user
specialCommand :: String -> InputT GHCi Bool
specialCommand ('!':str) = lift $ shellEscape (dropWhile isSpace str)
-- [...]

shellEscape :: String -> GHCi Bool
shellEscape str = liftIO (system str >> return False)
```

I suspect `system` is hardcoded to `/bin/sh`, but there's no reason you can't [define your own ghci command](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html#id3041426) to do `fish` calls. I don't have `fish` installed, so I'll use `bash` as an example:

```
λ import System.Process (rawSystem)
λ :def bash \cmd -> rawSystem "/bin/bash" ["-c", cmd] >> return ""
λ :bash echo $0
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for plus some nice extra information.

Comment: But be careful: shells typically distinguish between "interactive" use and "non-interactive use", and skip the startup files that define functions and aliases when used non-interactively. So even after this setup the stated goal may not be met.

Comment: `fish`, though, takes the opposite approach. All configuration files are processed on start-up, and special commands inside the configuration files detect whether the shell is interactive or a login shell.